# C++ valgrind error

Tags: c++, valgrind

I have simple program :

```
class stack{
public:
    void push(int a);
    void pop();
    int isempty();
    void init();
    void clear();
    int* stos;
    int size;
    private :
        int top;

    };

 void stack::init(){

        this->top=0;
        this->size=10;
        this->stos= reinterpret_cast<int*>(malloc(sizeof(int)*size));



    }
void stack::push(int a){
this->top++;
this->stos[top-1]=a;
if((this->top)>(this->size))
{
    this->size=2*(this->size);
    this->stos=reinterpret_cast<int*>(realloc(this->stos,sizeof(int)*(this->size)));

}


}
    void stack::pop()   
{
this->top--;

this->stos[this->top]=0;



}
 void stack::clear(){

free(this->stos);
this->top=0;

}
int stack::isempty(){
if((this->top)!=0)

    return -1;
else return 1;




 }
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
stack s1;
s1.init();
s1.clear();
printf("%d",s1.stos[12]);

return 0;

}
```

I'm begginer  in cpp, and valgrind returns such an error :

```
==4710== Invalid read of size 4
==4710==    at 0x80486D7: main (main.cpp:69)
==4710==  Address 0x4325058 is 8 bytes after a block of size 40 free'd
 ==4710==    at 0x402B06C: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==4710==    by 0x8048686: stack::clear() (main.cpp:51)
==4710==    by 0x80486CF: main (main.cpp:68)
==4710==
```

If there wont be clear() function in main error will be the same but will say that 40 alloc'd :)
I will be glad for any help, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are accessing memory that you have not allocated, when you do this:

```
printf("%d",s1.stos[12]);
```

In the first case, you call `s1.clear()`, which frees (de-allocates) the memory for s1.stos.

In the second case (if you get rid of `clear()`), you are accessing the 12th element of an array that you have only allocated 10 elements for.

Comment: Thanks :P It was just something that left from testing program :P I was stupid